# How to obtain information from tex-generated and ps-generated PDFs?

Tags: pdf

As a research mathematician I find it useful to sometimes read only the main results of a math paper. For a human this is usually very easy to achieve: Just open the PDF file or PS file and look for theorems in the first section. Since such a process is fairly easy I assume that it is possible to automate.

For a program to solve this problem we can let it do so in a few steps:

1. Obtain both the text and the style from the first section
2. Look for bold paragraphs as strings with initial substring "Theorem"
3. Collect such paragraphs

2 and 3 are easy to achieve. On the other hand 1 can be harder. In math papers on arXiv if we ignore really old papers that could be scanned pictures we mostly have the following three formats: Tex, PS and PDF. In Tex step 1 is very easy. However for PDF files, including PDF files generated by Tex it is something I really have no idea about.

How can step 1 be automated?

Comment: Try Finereader ))

Comment: I don't think I need OCR now. Instead I just want to make sure that the text itself and whether it is bold or italic are almost 100% correct for Tex-generated PDF files.

I'm checking out PDFminer now. Not sure whether it works well for my purpose.

Comment: https://www.pdftohtml.net/

Comment: @Piterden Thanks! Do you know any that is also possible to use when writing programs?

Comment: If you want a library for some programming language, you should mention the acceptable languages. Furthermore, such recommendations strictly speaking are off topic on stack overflow, there is an explicit software recommendations site in the stack exchange family.

Comment: @mkl Oh..I didn't know it. Python 2 is the best due to the existence of SageMath,  followed by Python 3, C/C++ and Java. I can learn some other language if necessary.